# Razor: @Html.Partial() vs @RenderPage()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, renderpartial

What is the appropriate way of rendering a child template?

And what's the difference? Both seem to work for me.

And why does `@Html.RenderPartial()` no longer work?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

```
Html.Partial("MyView")
```

Renders the "MyView" view to an `MvcHtmlString`.  It follows the standard rules for view lookup (i.e. check current directory, then check the `Shared` directory).

```
Html.RenderPartial("MyView")
```

Does the same as `Html.Partial()`, except that it writes its output directly to the response stream.  This is more efficient, because the view content is not buffered in memory.  However, because the method does not return any output, `@Html.RenderPartial("MyView")` won't work.  You have to wrap the call in a code block instead: `@{Html.RenderPartial("MyView");}`.

```
RenderPage("MyView.cshtml")
```

Renders the specified view (identified by path and file name rather than by view name) directly to the response stream, like `Html.RenderPartial()`.  You can supply any model you like to the view by including it as a second parameter

```
RenderPage("MyView.cshtml", MyModel)
```

Comment: Are there any metrics on the efficiency gain of @{Html.RenderPartial("MyView");} over @Html.RenderPartial("MyView")?

Comment: @Faust did you meant Partial vd RenderPartial ?

Comment: @cacho: yes, my comment should read `@Html.Partial("MyView")` vs. `@{Html.RenderPartial("MyView");}`

Comment: Small correction: the second parameter in RenderPage() isn't the model, it's a param[] Object which is accessed via the PageData property. It appears to work as above because by default  the model from the "parent" page is passed through to the "child". https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase.renderpage(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: Is there a way to nest a complete page along its model by calling `RenderPage`? I want to nest a different page by specifying a specific query parameter, which in turn would filter the data in that page, and in addition, remove its own layout.

Answer (score 17):

I prefer

```
@RenderPage("_LayoutHeader.cshtml")
```

Over

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_LayoutHeader"); }
```

Only because the syntax is easier and it is more readable. Other than that there doesn't seem to be any differences functionality wise.

EDIT: One advantage of RenderPartial is you don't have to specify the entire path or file extension it will search the common places automatically.

Comment: I think this should be a comment not answer. Also I agree with `RenderPage` because of the syntax.

Answer (score 6):

The **RenderPartial** method doesn’t return HTML markup like most other helper methods. Instead, it writes
content directly to the response stream, which is why we must call it like a complete line of C#, using a semicolon.

This is slightly more efficient than buffering the rendered HTML from the partial view, since it will be written to the
response stream anyway. If you prefer a more consistent syntax, you can use the **Html.Partial** method, which
does exactly the same as the **RenderPartial** method, but returns an HTML fragment and can be used as
@Html.Partial("Product", p).

Answer (score 2):

We can also pass model using partial views. @Html.Partial("MyView","MyModel");

Answer (score 0):

```
@RenderPages()
```

The above does not work in ASP.NET MVC. It only works in WebPages.

```
@Html.Partial("_Footer")
```

You will need to use the above in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET Core 7. In the Shared folder make partial file then user this following code

`<partial name="_NavBar" />`