# @Html.Action In Layout Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Thanks for reading this.

In the _Layout.cshtml page I use the @RenderPage to call the header:

```
@RenderPage("/Shared/_header.cshtml")
```

It has this:

```
<div id="Header"> Home </div>
```

Want to make it clickable to the default action ("Index")

When I tried this:

```
<div id="Header"> @Html.Action("Index", MyController") </div>
```

I get the error:

An opening "(" is missing the corresponding closing ")" at

```
@RenderPage("/Shared/_header.cshtml")
```

Any idea?

Comment: You should put the header directly in the layout page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the opening double-quote on MyController.

It should be:

```
<div id="Header"> @Html.Action("Index", "MyController") </div>
```

Comment: oh crap; I'm blind ...

So, I entered the double quote and I get this error:

    The 'Action' is underlined in red with this error:

'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a defintion for 'Action' and no extension ......

Comment: Try to use RenderPartial instead of RenderPage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501736/razor-html-partial-vs-renderpage