# MVC3 RenderPage never renders content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So I have this master/detail setup with a WebGrid. All is well until I try and use RenderPage to display the detail when a record is clicked:

```
<div class="innerbox">
    @{
        if(gdEligibility.HasSelection){
             @RenderPage("~/Views/Eligibility/EligibilityPolicyDetailView.cshtml",
                 new { Customer = gdEligibility.SelectedRow })
        }
    }
</div>
```

Everything works, if I put a break point I can step through the detail view's cshtml file no problem, no errors. But nothing is ever rendered between the outer div's. Ever. Why doesn't RenderPage return anything? I even tried adding .ToHtmlString() on the end of the line but still nothing.

The detail cshtml:

```
@{ foreach(TravelInsurance.Models.Policy p in Page.Customer.Policies){

<fieldset>
    <legend>Policy</legend>

    <div class="display-label">Policy Number</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => p.PolicyNumber)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Premium</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => p.Premium)
    </div>
</fieldset>
}}
```

Comment: What kind of file is your call to `@RenderPage()` contained in?

Comment: It's in a standard mvc View .cshtml file

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501736/razor-html-partial-vs-renderpage) question suggests that RenderPage will use the parent model...

Maybe try using

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("EligibilityPolicyDetailView", new { Customer = gdEligibility.SelectedRow });}
```

or

```
@Html.Partial("EligibilityPolicyDetailView" ,new { Customer = gdEligibility.SelectedRow })
```

Comment: Tried both with no luck. I ended up using Telerik's webgrid but I still don't know why this wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Pl. try again by removing the attribute "ajaxUpdateContainerId" in the grid definition and it should work.