# How to call a page from one sub directory to another sub directory with @RenderPage command?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I am working with ASP.NET. I am just a beginner to this development framework. Currently I am having a problem with the coad `@RenderPage`.

I wanted to call a page located on like this path `ASP_NET\Directory1\SubDirectory\page1` to this page `ASP_NET\Directory2\SubDirectory\page2` with `@RenderPage` command.

But I dont know how to do this, plz help anyone if there are any way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RenderPage("~/Directory2/SubDirectory/page2.cshtml")

Or look here [Razor: @Html.Partial() vs @RenderPage()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501736/razor-html-partial-vs-renderpage)